# How a set a "search" value to a variable in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

I had a value that is inserted in a input at index and led me to a show page.

But, when I insert and submit, I gain a Blank Page! However, if I type in the URL the path to the show item, it appears!

Print from the input on client side:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab5DD.jpg

I tried and get the following result with biding pry

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KuuS.jpg

The "entrega" really comes with the input that is the cient_number, but @entrega does'nt

So, When goes to if, all the values are nil. I really don't understand

I've tried the following code at Controller:

```
def sac_index
        #binding.pry
        @objectives = DeliveryObjective.all        
        @search = params["search"]    
        if @search.present?            
            @entrega = @search["client_number"]                      
            @objectives = DeliveryObjective.where(client_number: @entrega)             
        end
        #@search_uol = DeliveryObjective.where(client_number: params[:id])
    end

    def sac_show 
        #@delivery_objective = DeliveryObjective.where(client_number: @search)
        @delivery_objective  = DeliveryObjective.where(client_number: params[:id])
        binding.pry
    end
```

When I input the client_number, I want to be rendered to the show page from the item.

Answer (score 0):

Based in an earlier response, I resolved the conflict, changing the Controller:

```
def index
    @objectives = DeliveryObjective.all     

    @search = params["search"]    
    if @search.present?            
        @entrega = @search["client_number"]                     
        @objective = DeliveryObjective.where(client_number: @entrega)             
    end        
end

def show 
    @search = params["search"]    
    if @search.present?        
        @entrega = @search["client_number"]
    @delivery_objective = DeliveryObjective.where(client_number: @entrega)
   end             
end
```

It's a little bit dirty, but can help someone.

Comment: Its looks like the key in params is `entrega` not `client_number`. Maybe try to change this `@search["client_number"]` - `@search["entrega"]`

Comment: Yes Lukas, this is the question. The question is because someone deleted their response where contained this and I replied correctly as above. Regards